# Rebind keys in Emacs to change commenting style in source code

Tags: emacs, code-snippets, key-bindings

I am trying to document certain sections of my code using Doxygen. I want to use the javadoc 
style of comments viz

```
 /**
  *  My Documentation goes here
  */
```

Now in Emacs I can comment out a certain block of text by selecting it and by pressing `Meta`+`;`. This comments out the lines by placing a `//` in front of all the lines selected.

Since most of the time I will be writing comments in my code which will be documented using Doxygen, I want to rebind the  `Meta`+`;` to give me a javadoc style of comments.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [doxymacs](http://doxymacs.sourceforge.net/).  You'll have to rebind keys to your taste, but the bindings it comes with are pretty good.

Answer (score 1):

Code is not documentation.  Wouldn't you want to use javadoc style comments only for documentation?

It sounds like you actually want a snippet/skeleton system to insert a java-doc template that you can flesh out.  If so I recommend [yasnippet](https://github.com/capitaomorte/yasnippet).